# Overlaying traces in Mapbox for Python

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, geojson

I am currently working on a Geography project, for which I have to do some research on migration flows.

I want to represent migration flows using Python and Mapbox, based on a worldwide GeoJSON I previously downloaded. However, I am having some issues regarding the quality of the work, and can't find a proper solution.

I first uploaded the world GeoJSON:

```
countries = json.load(open("countries_without_antartica.geojson"))
```

I then extracted the coordinates with a function and grouped them into a list named `countries_coords`, with `countries_lons, countries_lats = zip(*countries_coords)`.

I then start creating the figure.

Firstly, I initiate it:

```
fig = go.Figure()
```

Then, I put the information I extracted before into a ScatterMapbox environment:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        mode='lines',
        name='Countries',
        fill='toself',
        fillcolor='lightgray',
        line=dict(color='black', width=1),
        lat=countries_lats,
        lon=countries_lons,
        opacity=1,
        showlegend=False,
        hoverinfo='skip',
))
```

I then specify the Mapbox style with: `fig.update_layout(mapbox=dict(style='white-bg'))`

That leaves the map with the GeoJSON data alone, as seen in this image: [image: IMAGE 1]

The problem, however, starts right here: I then try to add a line to the map, indicating the first migration flow (in this case, from Spain to Australia). I do this with the following code:

```
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scattermapbox(
            name='flow1',
            lon = [134.340916, -3.704239],
            lat = [-25.039402, 40.415887],
            mode = 'lines',
            line = dict(width = 8,color = 'green')
        )
)
```

However, the resulted figure is this:[image: IMAGE 2]

I have several problems with that, as the migration *flow* line should be a somewhat curved line and not a straight one.

I realized the solution to THAT (and only THAT) problem was to use go.Scattergeo instead of go.Scattermapbox to represent the line, and so I did:

```
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scattergeo(
            name='flow1',
            lon = [134.340916, -3.704239],
            lat = [-25.039402, 40.415887],
            mode = 'lines',
            line = dict(width = 8,color = 'green')
        )
)
```

**BUT** the line is now "behind" the map itself, so it is not visible (resulting in IMAGE 1 again).

The line with go.Scattergeo **IS** curved, and it **DOES** represent what I wanted it to represent, but it is not visible because it is "layered" behind the go.ScatterMapbox figure with the map.

How can I change the order of the traces? Is there a way to prevent the first trace from being "above" the second trace? I tried changing the order of appearance, but nothing worked.

**EDIT 1**
Following the solutions provided by @NikolasStevenson-Molnar and @BasvanderLinden, I rendered both the world and the migration flow by using `go.Scattergeo`. Code here:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        mode='lines',
        name='Countries',
        fill='toself',
        fillcolor='lightgray',
        line=dict(color='black', width=1),
        lat=countries_lats,
        lon=countries_lons,
        opacity=1,
        showlegend=False,
        hoverinfo='skip',
))

fig.add_trace(
        go.Scattergeo(
            name='flow1',
            lon = [134.340916, -3.704239],
            lat = [-25.039402, 40.415887],
            mode = 'lines',
            line = dict(width = 8,color = 'green')
        )
)
```

Here, the result:[image: IMAGE 3]

As you can see, the map is not as "great" as it should be. Some issues regarding it's quality are:

1. The countries are filled with the same colors as the background (i.e. the oceans). I cannot find a way to fill **only** de countries. While using `go.Scattermapbox` this was easily done by specifying the desired style (`fig.update_layout(mapbox=dict(style='white-bg'))`). However, 'go.Scattergeo' does not have that functionality.
2. The map seems to be outstretched horizontally (see how all the countries are way more wide in IMAGE 3 compared to IMAGE 1). This is particularly visible in the northern hemisphere.

It then occurred to me that issue 1 should be solved by "turning off" the filling atributes, so I coded:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        mode='lines',
        name='Countries',
        line=dict(color='black', width=1),
        lat=countries_lats,
        lon=countries_lons,
        opacity=1,
        showlegend=False,
        hoverinfo='skip',
))
```

Result is, again, not desirable, because the GeoJSON is plot *above* the default map that 'go.Scattergeo` provides. For example, when I zoom in into Spain, I get:[image: IMAGE 4] Clearly, the two traces (default and GeoJSON) are operating at the same time, making the final result not-so-tidy. On top of that, the default trace just shows "territory", but not "political division", so -for example- Portugal is not drawn in the default trace but it is in the GeoJSON.

Hope this extra information is valuable to reach a proper solution.

Thank you in advance, for any help, advice, or solution you might give me.

Comment: How about using `Scattergeo` to render both the world _and_ the line?

Comment: Hi Nikolas! I already tried that but using ```Scattergeo``` to render the world does not allow to plot the GeoJSON *while* having another background color. That is why I "need" to use ```Scattermapbox```, as it allows to use any style I want. Moreover, even if I ignore the background task, ```Scattergeo``` plots the GeoJSON ABOVE the classsic and default world-map, resulting in two different traces for each country. Unfortunately, I can't post an image in comments. Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @justanotherguy You can set a background color for the map with Scattergeo also. I don't really understand the second thing you mentioned in your previous comment, maybe edit the question and post an image of that problem?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I have just updated the publication. Hope this information is valuable. I thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can go back to basics and calculate your own great circle line
- https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/examples.html#basic-geodesic-calculations has an example of how to achieve this
- bringing it together

  - source countries GeoJSON and create a **geopandas** dataframe
  - use **centroid** capability to have data for the centre of a country
  - build utility function to calculate a great circle trace
  - finally show it in action with lines between three pairs of countries

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json, io
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
import math

# source geojson for country boundaries so we can calc centroids
geosrc = pd.json_normalize(
    requests.get(
        "https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/geo-countries/7/datapackage.json"
    ).json()["resources"]
)
fn = Path(geosrc.loc[geosrc["name"].eq("geo-countries_zip"), "path"].values[0]).name

if not Path.cwd().joinpath(fn).exists():
    r = requests.get(
        geosrc.loc[geosrc["name"].eq("geo-countries_zip"), "path"].values[0],
        stream=True,
    )
    with open(fn, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)

zfile = ZipFile(fn)
with zfile.open(zfile.infolist()[0]) as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geojson).set_index("ISO_A3")
# centroids...
gdf["lon"] = gdf.apply(lambda r: r.geometry.centroid.x, axis=1)
gdf["lat"] = gdf.apply(lambda r: r.geometry.centroid.y, axis=1)


def worldcircleline(gdf, country1, country2, fig=None, color="blue"):
    geod = Geodesic.WGS84  # define the WGS84 ellipsoid

    l = geod.InverseLine(
        gdf.loc[country1, "lat"],
        gdf.loc[country1, "lon"],
        gdf.loc[country2, "lat"],
        gdf.loc[country2, "lon"],
        Geodesic.LATITUDE | Geodesic.LONGITUDE,
    )

    da = 1
    n = int(math.ceil(l.a13 / da))
    da = l.a13 / n

    lat = [
        l.ArcPosition(
            da * i, Geodesic.LATITUDE | Geodesic.LONGITUDE | Geodesic.LONG_UNROLL
        )["lat2"]
        for i in range(n + 1)
    ]
    lon = [
        l.ArcPosition(
            da * i, Geodesic.LATITUDE | Geodesic.LONGITUDE | Geodesic.LONG_UNROLL
        )["lon2"]
        for i in range(n + 1)
    ]

    tfig = px.line_mapbox(
        lat=lat,
        lon=lon,
        mapbox_style="carto-positron",
        zoom=1,
    ).update_traces(line={"color":color})

    if fig is None:
        return tfig.update_layout(margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "b": 0, "t": 0})
    else:
        return fig.add_traces(tfig.data)


fig = worldcircleline(gdf, "ESP", "AUS")
worldcircleline(gdf, "GBR", "SGP", fig=fig, color="red")
worldcircleline(gdf, "IRL", "USA", fig=fig, color="green")
```

[image]

Comment: It worked wonderfully! It took me a while to install geopandas correctly and understand all the steps, but it was the most helpful solution I got to the problem. Nice workaround and approach! Thank you, @RobRaymond.